# pipe returns 0 but read_fd is set to 0

Tags: c++, linux

I have a program that uses `pipe`in linux to create events that can be used in conjunction with `epoll`. That events sometimes get deleted and later re-created. Upon one of these calls `pipe` return 0 (successful), but in the array for the filedescriptors the read fd (index 0) is set to 0 and upon writing to the write fd (index 1) I get an `SIGPIPE`. I did not find anywhere anything  on that and even creating a small test program does not reproduce this issue.

This is how the pipe is created:

```
    int fd[2] = {};

    const int err (pipe(fd));
    if (err)
    {
        printf("Error creating pipe (%d)\n", errno);
    }

    int read_fd = fd[0];
    int write_fd = fd[1];
```

Is that behaviour anywhere documented or does anybody know what might cause this?

Comment: did you really miss `=` in `const int err = pipe(fd);`? If so, `pipe()` is declared but not called

Comment: sorry, the tag is wrong, its actually c++ code

Comment: `0` is a valid file descriptor. `I get an SIGPIPE` Then - please post an [MCVE]`

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis:

- you explicitly or implicitly close your standard input (`close(0);` or  `fclose(stdin);` ) before actual call to pipe()
- as result, descriptor 0 is considered "free" and used as fd[0], i.e. read side of created pipe
- then you once more explicitly or implicitly perform `close(0);`
- as result, you have pipe with closed read side
- finally, when you try to write to fd[1], you get SIGPIPE as expected in case, when read side is closed.

If this hypothesis is correct, you need to understand who closes periodically (at least twice) descriptor 0 of your current process

Comment: So, you need to build at least issue reproduction example